# How can I get a traceback for TypeError: can't pickle generator objects?

Tags: python, pickle

I'm getting this error when trying to run my code using multiprocess on Python. I understand the error, but I'm hoping I can somehow get a traceback to the actual line with the generators (it's a lot of code & I can't find the bugs).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 241, in _feed
    obj = ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle generator objects
```

How can I get it to show where it got stuck?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34033754/how-to-debug-when-using-multiprocessing-in-pycharm

Comment: I think this error occurs prior to the dispatch to other processes